# Ruby SQL query inter related attributes

Tags: sql, ruby

I have three tables skills_development, training_programs and participants. skills_development has many training_programs and training_programs have many participants. training_programs also have different categories A-F, and participants have different genders.

I want to be able to access all participants within a skills development that are female and that belong to training programs A-C.

Is there a way to do this with a single query?

I can do

```
tp = @skills_development.training_programs.where("category = ?", "A")
```

to get all the training programs with category A

```
p = @skill_development.participants.where("gender = ?", "female")
```

and all female participants

But how to mix these together is frying my brain. i thought you could just

```
tp = @skills_development.training_programs.where("category = ?", "A")
tp.participants.where("gender = ?", "female")
```

But i get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `participant' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc7e6bcdaa8>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the tables.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

This *should* work:

```
participants = Participant.joins(:training_programs).
  where('training_programs.skills_development_id' => @skills_development.id).
  where('training_programs.category' => %w(A B C)).
  where('participants.gender' => 'female')
```